# Workflow with REST call save as template

Tags: workflow, rest

I have created a workflow which does a lot of REST calls. The workflow works perfectly and I have several other sites/lists were I will need the same workflow. Therefore I would like to save the workflow as a template, and then upload and activate it in another site/list. The only problem is that all the REST calls fx. go:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/Lists/GetbyTitle(‘ListName’)/items?Select=Titel
```

Meaning that the "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/" part is specific to one site, which is a problem when I implement it to different sites.

Is it possible to do a lookup for that part, or type the URL in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USe the workflow context variable "Current Site URL" when building the REST url as below
[image: Workflow Context: Current Site Url]
[image: Built URL]